# How to remove all unnecessary characters from Exception message stack?

Tags: java, android, string

I want to report exception issues to backend, however, there are a lot of special characters that require to be removed. For example, `\u003c` (<) and `\u003e` (>) signs from this node.

```
{
   "declaringClass":"android.widget.Toast",
   "fileName":"Toast.java",
   "isNativeMethod":false,
   "lineNumber":208,
   "methodName":"\u003cinit\u003e"
}
```

I also witness `\u0027` (apostrophes) as well.

```
"detailMessage":"Attempt to invoke virtual method \u0027java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()\u0027 on a null object reference"
```

Lastly, whenever there are class references, dollar signs are added.

```
com.test.ExceptionFragment$1trackExceptions$1(ExceptionFragment.java:201)
```

Is there some universal way of sanitizing these sort of symbols out of JSON? Or is regex the best solution? If regex, what regex will address the above described scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

str = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);

Further reference can be taken from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

Other references
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html

UnicodeUnescaper from org.apache.commons:commons-text is also acceptable.

new UnicodeUnescaper().translate("\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F World") returns "Hello World"

Answer (score 0):

Why do you regard those characters as "unneccesary" ?

`<init>` is not the same thing as `init`, so your error report could end up being confusing.

Likewise, a dollar sign is an important character in a class name.

Comment: The $ can be replaced with a period. Just represents the path.

Comment: It's a compiler-generated name.  `foo.bar` is not `foo$bar`

Comment: The $ is a separator that indicates that there is a nested class. Look here: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077489/core-java/java-tip-124--trace-your-steps-in-java-1-4.html.

The nested classes are distinguished from the higher-level nested classes and from the top-level class by using the dollar sign character ($). So, technically, the "simple" name of the second nested class is StackTrace$FirstNested$SecondNested.